# Extract Specified Information From Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, text-extraction

Suppose I have a word document that the contents is like below

```
Name: Blabla1
Address: Blablabla2
History Employment: Blablabla3
                    Blablabla4
                    Blablabla5
```

And my questions here is how and what algorithm (if exist) to extract that information into class in C#.

```
Class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> History = new IList<string>();
}
```

Any suggestion ?

```
var Employee = ExtractMethodFromDoc(docPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

MS Word is totally scriptable, via OLE Automation.

There are no generic libraries in c# for this purpose. You can use third-party app to convert to another format, such as ASCII.

You can also refer this link to PERL module for this purpose:

http://www.xav.com/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE.html

You can also refer to this MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974107%28office.12%29.aspx

You can also use this Open XML SDK 2.0 Code link below:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17985

Comment: conversion to other format might not be the best solution, there is no grantee that all info is kept during the conversion.

Comment: @David I searched it but found no alternative, sorry, see this additional SDK if helpful >> http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/17/t/5992.aspx

Comment: your comment is too absolute, strongly disagree, pardon me for that, :). You don't have to use script such as powershell. For instance, in Visual studio, you can use Document-level customizations (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942839.aspx) to access all content of word doc, it is then not too hard to parse the text into structure representation such as  class instances that hold the required info.

Comment: @David Thanx, very useful link. I was unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft word dll.
create object of word dll and load data.